# Hudson error: Unsupported Maven version: 3.0?

Tags: hudson, maven-3

I configured a local installation of Maven3 in Hudson, and when I tried to build my project using that Maven installation, I get the error: **Unsupported Maven version: 3.0**. I cannot find documentation that says Hudson does not support Maven v3. What is wrong with Hudson or my configuration?

```
[INFO] Checking Maven 3 installation environment
[workspace] $ C:\apache-maven-3.0\bin\mvn.bat --help
[INFO] Checking Maven 3 installation version
[INFO] Detected Maven 3 installation version: 3.0
[ERROR] Failure: hudson.AbortException: Unsupported Maven version: 3.0
ERROR: Unsupported Maven version: 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the freestyle project type and the maven 3 build step. Then you do not even need a local Maven 3 install and things will just work. Look at the free [Hudson Book](http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Hudson_Book) I wrote for more documentation on the Maven 3 integration.